# Events not binding for serve side rendered component

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, reactjs.net

I am using reactjs.net to render components server side. My problem is, I have been asked to get the HTML strings for both the component and the corresponding javascript via an ajax call and render the component.

This is my method which gives the HTML string.

```
  public JsonResult GetComponent(string strComponentName)
  {
        string strHtml = "";
        IHtmlContent htmlc= HtmlHelperExtensions.React(null, String.Format("Components.{0}", strComponentName), new { });
        strHtml = GetString(htmlc);
       IHtmlContent jscript  = HtmlHelperExtensions.ReactInitJavaScript(null);
        string strJavascript = GetString(jscript);
        jsonresponse jr = new jsonresponse();
        jr.html = strHtml;
        jr.javascript = strJavascript;
        return Json(jr);
 }
```

Now, this function is called on the click event of a few buttons. After the received strings are rendered.

```
 fetchComp() {
     let FETCH_URL: string = "/Home/GetComponent?strComponentName=" + this.props.componentName;
     fetch(FETCH_URL, {
         method: 'GET'
     })
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(json => {
             console.log("json from wrapper", json);
             const html = json.html;
             const javascript = json.javascript;
             this.setState({ html: html, javascript: javascript,rendered: true });
             console.log("state val", this.state);


         });
}
```

the render method is as follows

```
 render() {
     if (!this.state.rendered) {
         this.fetchComp();
     }
return (<div>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.html+" <script src=\"~/dist/client.bundle.js\"></script>" +this.state.javascript }} />


</div>);
}
```

The events for the rendered component are not working. even though the javascript required events have been rendered along with the component.

Edit: I also tried adding the script to the main body by creating a script element and appending to document.body. didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured out the problem. Just rendering the javascript code wont attach the events. you need the code to be executed for the events to be attached.Remove  tags from your javascript string then use eval function.

```
  eval(this.state.javascript.replace('<script>','').replace('</script>',''));
```

**Disclaimer**: eval is known to cause problems. though i haven't encountered any.

Answer (score 0):

`render() {
     if (!this.state.rendered) {
         this.fetchComp();
     }`

In this part you are calling fetchComp function which has setState method.  You should not directly set a state without binding through events.  This will create an infinite loop and makes your application behave weird

Comment: I am not setting state directly anywhere

Comment: I guess you will have the 'rendered' state as false initially.  So during the initial load it will call 'fetchComp' method which makes the fetch call.  You set the state there with the data and making 'rendered' state true.                This setState is done directly done from render.  This will cause infinite loop.  Check the console:-)

Comment: yes. but that is not the problem. It renders correctly. but after rendering, the clickevents in the rendered components do not fire.